# Attempting to write to document but nothing is loading

Tags: javascript

So this is my first attempt at Javascript and it's probably really messy. The whole point of it is to output the date with each part of the date being different colours. I've looked at a few ways of doing it and this is what I've come up with (HTML added by request):

```
<body>

<p id="calendar"></p>


<script>
    var d = new Date();
    var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "brown"];
    var i;
    var fulldate = [];

    var fulldate[0] = days[d.getDay()];
    var fulldate[1] = d.getDate();
    var fulldate[2] = months[d.getMonth()];
    var fulldate[3] = d.getFullYear();
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var fulldate[4] = hours + ":" + minutes

        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:"colors[i]"\">" fulldate[i] "</span>"
        }
</script>
</body>
```

I'm trying to work out why it's not displaying anything at all in the paragraph tag I've written. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Is the paragraph tag before or after the `<script>` tag?

Comment: before the script tag. I've put the script at the bottom of the body section of the HTML file.

Comment: Can you also post the HTML for this?

Comment: Just added the HTML, there's not exactly much.

Comment: You need `+` in between your string and variable declarations in the `("calendar").innerHTML = ...` bit :)

Comment: look in your Browser Developer Tools for errors that **will** be there

Comment: And you could `var i = 0` *inside* your `for` loop, rather than declaring it ages away near the top :)

Comment: D'oh! I knew something looked wrong. And now it's only outputting the time :/

Comment: Downvoting the question for posting before checking for errors in the Javascript console.

Comment: I did check the errors in javascript console. It came up with an unknown identifier and I googled that and couldn't get an answer on what it meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there!

Couple of things that you could do with doing:

**1.** You need to concatenate your `string`s and `variable`s where you're setting the `innerHTML` of your `p` element using the `+` symbol between string and variable

e.g. `"A string" + myVariable` or `aVariable + "some string" + anotherVariable`

**2.** Initialize `i` (the counter for your `for` loop) within the `for` declaration - you don't need to declare this before your loop, and it's easier to read in future

Remove the `var i;` declaration near the top - it's a bit lost. Then, in your `for(...)` statement, you can just initialize `i`, there.

e.g. `for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { ... }`

**3.** You're replacing the `innerHTML` of your `#calendar` every iteration of the for loop. You can use `+=` to append to an existing value.

e.g. `document.getElementById('calendar').innerHTML += "...";`

---

Your code should look something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document
        .getElementById("calendar")
        .innerHTML += "<span style=\"color:" + colors[i] + "\">" + fulldate[i] + "</span>";
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm trying to follow the w3c best practise thingie but yeah, declaring it so early feels weird. Now it's only displaying the final element in the array and that doesn't look right, shouldn't it start at 0 and print each one in turn?

Comment: You're right - I've just realised, that each iteration is replacing the `innerHTML` of the `calender` element. Use `+=` to append the string :)

Comment: zomg! I could kiss you! Thank you so much for your help, Geoff. I was beating my head against my desk trying to figure this out!

Comment: Pleasure's all mine and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there. you need to use`+` to concatenate string.

Try this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:" + colors[i] + "\">" + fulldate[i] + "</span>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code. you have to supply a string in innerHTML and use + to add dynamic data to a string.

```
var d = new Date();
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "brown"];
var i;
var fulldate = [];
    console.log(d.getDay());
 fulldate.push(days[d.getDay()]);
 fulldate.push(d.getDate());
 fulldate.push(months[d.getMonth()]);
 fulldate.push(d.getFullYear());
 hours = d.getHours();
 minutes = d.getMinutes();
fulldate.push(hours + ":" + minutes);

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:"+colors[i]+"\">" + fulldate[i] + "</span>"
    }
```

You can see the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/dt3evpjn/13/